# Exiting Word Table after pasting from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to copy information from an excel sheet to a new word document. Currently everything copies correctly on the first loop, but pastes into the previously pasted table in the next loop. I've tried every variation of ways to exit the table I can find through searching and none seem to fix the issue. Hoping someone can help.

```
Sub createWord()
Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Dim heading As New DataObject
Dim fileName As String
Dim tableRange As Word.Range
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
fileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
fileName = Left$(fileName, InStrRev(fileName, ".") - 1) & " Data.doc"
'objDoc.SaveAs fileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileName
objWord.Visible = True

For i = 4 To Application.Sheets.Count
    Dim k As Integer
    k = ((i - 4) * 4) + 1
    
    heading.SetText ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells(1, 4).Value
    heading.PutInClipboard
    objDoc.Paragraphs.Add
    objDoc.Paragraphs(k).Range.Paste
    k = k + 1
    
    
    Call copyGraphAuto(i)
    objDoc.Paragraphs.Add
    objDoc.Paragraphs(k).Range.Paste
    k = k + 1
    
    heading.SetText ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells(24, 5).Value
    heading.PutInClipboard
    objDoc.Paragraphs.Add
    objDoc.Paragraphs(k).Range.Paste
    k = k + 1
    
    Call copyTableAuto(i)
    objDoc.Paragraphs.Add
    objDoc.Paragraphs(k).Range.Paste
    
    Set tableRange = objDoc.Tables(k - 3).Range
    tableRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd

    'Exit For
Next i
```

End Sub

```
Sub copyTableAuto(Optional ByVal sheetNumber As Integer)
Dim ppmCount As Integer
    If sheetNumber = 0 Then sheetNumber = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Index
    ppmCount = Worksheets(sheetNumber).Range("M4:M9").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Worksheets(sheetNumber).Range("E29:E" & CStr(ppmCount + 28)).Merge
    Worksheets(sheetNumber).Range("E25:I" & CStr(ppmCount + 28)).Copy
    
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by your attempt to maintain an index of the paragraphs in the document.

As you are adding data to the document consecutively it would be better, and simpler, to use Word's own index and work with:

```
objDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range
```

Comment: Such a simple solution, and worked perfectly. Thank you very much.